# What is wrong with my Java quicksort implementation?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm pretty sure I understand how quicksort works, but I can't find the bug that's causing my attempt at implementing it to not work. I've looked through this for hours and can't figure out what's wrong. Please help me! Here is the entire file (It's just quicksort - nothing extra. The array is just random numbers for testing the quicksort.)

```
public class Quicksort{ 

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] arr = {5,1,4,3,7,0,9,2,6,8};
        quicksort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
        for(int x : arr)
          System.out.print(x+" ");
    }

    public static void quicksort(int[] arr, int start, int end){
        if(end-start<2)
            return; 
        int pivot = (end-start)/2;
        int i = start; 
        int k = end;
        while(k>i){
            while(arr[i]<arr[pivot]&&k>i&&i<=end)
                i++; 
            while(arr[k]>arr[pivot]&&k>=i)
                k--; 
            if(k>i){
                swap(arr, i, k); 
            }
        }
        swap(arr, pivot, i);

        quicksort(arr, 0, i);
        quicksort(arr, k, arr.length-1);
     }

     public static void swap(int[] a, int x, int y){
         int temp = a[x]; 
         a[x] = a[y]; 
         a[y] = temp; 
     }
}
```

As it is right now, the loop never terminates... it's a forever infinite loop! Please help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: To make things easier to read,I highly recommend breaking up the method into a recursive method called quicksort and a method that performs the partitioning.  That will make the code way easier to understand.

Comment: and fix the indentation while you are at it

Comment: The indentation is correct in my actual code, but I have trouble figuring out how to format it in stackoverflow. For some reason the 4 spaces at the beginning only format the first line into code. And it wouldn't let me use a pre block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base case should be `if(end-start<1)` - You only want to stop sorting when the number of elements is 1 (i.e. if `start` and `end` are equal)

Your while loops should just be `while(arr[i]<arr[pivot])` and `while(arr[k]>arr[pivot])`

This

```
if(k>i){
    swap(arr, i, k); 
}
```

should be

```
if(k>=i){
    swap(arr, i, k);
    i++;
    k--;
}
```

`swap(arr, pivot, i);` is unnecessary.

Your recursive call should be `quicksort(arr, start, k);` and `quicksort(arr, i, end);`

Answer (score 5):

Do yourself a favor and [learn how to use a debugger](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html). It makes solving this kind of problems very easy.

Comment: StackOverflow is the most user-friendly, easiest-to-use, no-learning-curve debugger...

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things that stand out --

1. Your end condition seems incorrect. If your array has just 2 elements, it won't sort them.
2. Also, after you do the swap, you need to increment and i and decrement k.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(arr[i]<arr[pivot]&&k>i&&i<=end)
```

Clearly you have had array index problems. All these tests aren't required in a working Quicksort, and the ones that are are in the wrong order.